# How to receive and save data via ajax in django?

Tags: html, django, django-forms

through ajax I am sending the data correctly, because the data I see through wireshak and they are correct. On the django server, he sends me the correct request "POST / solit / HTTP / 1.1" 200 52. But the value sent does not receive it, it does not reach the Mysql database and I do not understand why, if the traffic sends well the data.

In wireshak I see the data of the post request, they are the correct ones, but they are not saved in the database, when I want them to be added as if I were to update the record of such database fields and it does not , I do not understand why

this is my views.py

```
def solit(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    form = addiForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        peticion = form.save(commit=False)
        peticion.usuario = request.user
        peticion.save()
        peticion.usuario.d_pendientes = form.cleaned_data.POST.get('d_pendientes')
        peticion.usuario.h_pendientes = form.cleaned_data.POST.get('h_pendientes')
        peticion.usuario.save()   
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'true', 'msg': 'Procesado Correctamente'})

form = addiForm()
return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', {'form':form})
```

This is my models.py------------------------------

```
class Usuarios(AbstractUser):

    numero_empleado = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= True)
    area = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null= True, blank= True)
    d_pendientes = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= False)
    h_pendientes = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= False)
    f_init = models.DateField(max_length = 200,null= True, blank= True)
    init_vac = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null= True, blank= True)
    fin_vac = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null= True, blank= True)
    ul_vac_tomadas = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= True)


class Peticion(models.Model):
    solit_choices = (
    ('Adicionar','Adicionar'),
)
    solicitudes_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuarios, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    petit = models.CharField(max_length = 255, choices=solit_choices, null=True, blank=False)
    fec = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    razon = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    periodo_init = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    periodo_fin = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    dias_adicion = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    horas_adicion = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)
```

this is my forms.py

```
class addiForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    """Formulario de solicitud"""

    model = Peticion

    fields = [

        'solicitudes_id',
        'petit',
        'razon',
        'periodo_init',
        'periodo_fin',
        'dias_adicion',
        'horas_adicion',

    ]

    labels = {

        'solicitud_id':'Solicitud',
        'petit':'Tipo de Petición',
        'razon':'Razon',
        'periodo_init':'Rango de fecha inicial',
        'periodo_fin':'Fecha final',
        'dias_adicion':'Dias a adicionar, si es mas de 8 horas',
        'horas_adicion':'Horas a adiciona, si es menos de 1 dia',
```

html file

```
{% extends "plantillas/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% now "Y-m-d H:i:s" %} <br>
{{ user.Peti}}
{{ user.numero_empleado}}
<script src="{% static 'js/int.js'%}"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div><form method="POST" id="demo" class="form-data" action="{% url 'solit' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
    <h6>Tipo de peticion:{{form.petit}}</h6>
    <h6>Razon:{{form.razon}}</h6>
    <h6>{{form.solicitudes_id}}</h6>
    <h6>Fecha inicio:{{form.periodo_init}}</h6>
    <h6>Fecha fin:{{form.periodo_fin}}</h6>
    <h6>Introduzca dias a tomar<input id="dias" type="number" name="dias_adicion"></h6>
    <h6>Introduzca horas a tomar<input id="horas" type="number" name="horas_adicion"></h6>
    <input type="hidden" id="const_dias" name="d_pendientes" value="{{ user.d_pendientes }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="const_horas" name="h_pendientes" value="{{ user.h_pendientes }}">

    <button type="submit" onclick="calculo()">Guardar</button>
</div></form></span>
<h6>Recuerde, que usted dispone de {{ user.d_pendientes }} dias y {{ user.h_pendientes }} horas</h6>
```

js file---------------------

```
function calculo()

{

    var dias = parseInt(document.getElementById('dias').value);
    var horas = parseFloat(document.getElementById('horas').value);
    var dias_base  = parseInt(document.getElementById('const_dias').value);
    var horas_base  = parseFloat(document.getElementById('const_horas').value);

    dias_base -= dias;
    horas_base -= horas;

    document.getElementById('const_dias').value = dias_base;
    document.getElementById('const_horas').value = horas_base;



} console.log(calculo);
```

server django console [24/Jul/2019 15:30:47] "POST /solit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52 and the js console msg: "Procesado Correctamente"
status: "true"

ajax script--------------------------------------------

```
$(document).ready(function(calculo){
var productForm = $("#demo")

productForm.submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var thisForm = $(this)
  var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("action");
  var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
  var formData = thisForm.serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url: actionEndpoint,
    method: httpMethod,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data){
      console.log("success")
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(erroData){
      console.log("error")
      console.log(erroData)
    }
  })

 })
})
```

Comment: How do you know it is not saved in the database?

Comment: please add JavaScript code

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I have a main html page with user data and it does not update exactly the fields labeled {{user.d_dependents}} and {{user.h_dependents}}

Comment: @DiegoAvila js file added thanks

Comment: But that doesn't follow at all. You don't pass any data for usario in your form, so the `if peticion.usuario` condition will always be false and those fields are never updated.

Comment: @DanielRoseman 
I understand, thanks for your answer, what do I have to change in the code? Where? in the view? Show me please, how would you do it?

Comment: Where do you want the user data to come from?

Comment: hi @DanielRoseman The user's data is already in the database, the request would be by the same user logged in through a form to update their data through a mathematical operation, which I do from my js file, then send through ajax to django, but that django is not updating or saving that data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman 
thank you very much i appreciate it !! Now in the field, I get null, why? At least change something now, I really appreciate it, thanks! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still haven't really explained where you want the value for "usario" to come from. I'm going to assume that you want it to be the currently logged-in user. In which case, you can do this:

```
form = addiForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    peticion = form.save(commit=False)
    peticion.usuario = request.user
    peticion.save()
    peticion.usuario.d_pendientes = form.cleaned_data.get('d_pendientes')
    peticion.usuario.h_pendientes = form.cleaned_data.get('h_pendientes')
    peticion.usuario.save()   
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'true', 'msg': 'Procesado Correctamente'})
```

(Note, `.get` is a method, it needs parentheses not square brackets. And None is the default, you don't need to specify it explicitly.)

**Edit**

I'm finding it really hard to understand what you are asking, but I think your problem is that you simply don't have anything in the form called `dias_adicionar` or `horas_adicionar`; they are called `d_pendientes` and `h_pendientes` in line with your actual field names.

Comment: The "usario" value is consulted in the database, that value already defined is part of your data, only it is consulted. I added your corrections, but I still don't update the user field and edit your answer with what I have in my views.py currently

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "consulted".

Comment: A user logs in to the application has 3 apples already available in a field of the custom user model, but through a form that in turn has another model and is a modelform, add 2 apples, how do I add those 2 apples? I got to understand? thank for everything

Comment: I've updated the code above; but I've rejected your edit that added an `if` statement. There is a reason I didn't put in that `if`; it will *never be true*. Please remove it from your code, and follow the structure I have shown.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have had those POST attributes, updated again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it! Now in the field in the MYSQL database I find NULL and in the template, none appears because? At least change something now, I really appreciate it, thanks! I edited my models.py changing the attributes of null = True and white = False, but it still comes out because?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in your JavaScript code which makes an AJAX request - it's just a normal form POST request. This means `request.is_ajax()` will be false, and the form saving code doesn't execute.

Comment: Hi @GavinH ajax script added in my question.

Comment: The question still doesn't have enough information about what you see. Is anything logged to the browser console? Does the page refresh? Do any of your Python `print` statements get logged to the console?

Comment: Okay, sorry, in the javascript console, this appears to me: {status: "true", msg: "Procesado Correctamente"} returns the json of the post request, telling me that the sending of the data was successful, I I see the data in the request post by wireshak. in the Django console, it shows me the following: "POST / solit / HTTP / 1.1" 200 52 code 200 is an Ok at the reception of the post request. It does not reload the page because I send it asynchronously by ajax, but the logged-in user value is not updated and I see the data that should be put in the "h_pendientes" and "d_dependientes" fields